# How to open current link/folder under cursor in a new tab using command

Tags: linux, mouse, arch-linux, xbindkeys

Currently, I am using the mouse's middle button to open links in the browser, folder in file manager to open in a new tab. But my mouse's middle button is very sensitive and gets scrolled while pressing. I am thinking of assigning this function to the side button.
Please, can anyone tell me what command I need to assign? Thanks